# using pointers and "^=" to swap values

Tags: c

I try to swap values by using ^= (i know it is better to use another variable to do this),
but the result isn't correct.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a = 3, b = 5, *pa = &a, **ppa = &pa, *pb = &b, **ppb = &pb;
    *pa ^= *pb;
    *pb ^= *pa;
    *pa ^= *pb;
    printf("pointer 1: a = %d, b = %d\n", a, b);
    a ^= b ^= a ^= b;
    printf("variables: a = %d, b = %d\n", a, b);
    *pa ^= *pb ^= *pa ^= *pb;
    printf("pointer 2: a = %d, b = %d\n", a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

The result is

```
pointer 1: a = 5, b = 3
variables: a = 3, b = 5
pointer 2: a = 0, b = 3
```

I want to know why `*pa ^= *pb ^= *pa ^= *pb`doesn't work properly. Can any one tell me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no sequence point between the assignments in

```
*pa ^= *pb ^= *pa ^= *pb;
```

So the behaviour is not defined.

Neither is there a sequence point between the assignments in

```
a ^= b ^= a ^= b;
```

So the behaviour of that line is also undefined. If that happened to work then you were (un)lucky.

Comment: @MOHAMED and your point is? Undefined behavior is just that: *undefined*. Might work; might not. Don't confuse it with evidence-based behavior, which is inherently flawed in the first place.

Comment: So you have to mention in your answer that even if it worked in the first case that means always is always UB

Comment: @MOHAMED OK I've done that. I thought your original comment was implying that what I was stating was incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

You need an intervening sequence point. Otherwise, this is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Before answering your question I would like to introduce:

### [Sequence point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point):

> A sequence point is a point in time at which the dust has settled and all side effects which have been seen so far are guaranteed to be complete.

### The Standard states that:

> Between the previous and next sequence point an object shall have its **stored value modified at most once** by the evaluation of an expression. Furthermore, the prior value shall be accessed only to determine the value to be stored.

Now, your problem is that, in the expressions

```
a ^= b ^= a ^= b;
```

and

```
 *pa ^= *pb ^= *pa ^= *pb;
```

There is only one sequence point `;` (at the end of expressions) and you are modifying `a` **twice** in first expression and `*pa` in second expression between two sequence point (previous `;` and the `;` at the end of these expressions here) which causes the behavior of program **undefined**.

Further reading: [comp.lang.c FAQ list · Question 3.8](http://www.c-faq.com/expr/seqpoints.html).